# Animated bendy bone for copy position is wonky

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints, pose-mode, auto-rig-pro

Working with bendy bones and Auto Rig Pro.
 https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/properties/bendy_bones.html
**I am animating this bendy bone with a handle.** All fine and dandy. The true transforming bones in the neck are four separate bones that are supposed follow each other. This might not be optimal, but the ARP state forces me to keep these bones. 
[image: Bendy bone transformed]
My plan: Basically the four separate bones shall fill out the space of the bendy bone, no matter which position, so I have a neck that follows the curve of the bendy bone.
My problem: I tried different settings, but it never truly follows the curve of my bone, when moved in pose mode, or the initial position looks wonky compared to rest position. 
(Rest position see the aligned bones:).
[image: Rest Position]
I tried a copy position constraint, then read copy transforms is better for shear and twist. [image: Copy Position Constraint]
I tried Local Space, I tried World Space, neither works the way I need it- Pose Space looks just broken. The bones snap outside of the curve, just like in the first image, they need to be properly aligned in order for the animation to look correct, though. And I tried to find a way using different head/tail values, I tried Copy Transforms as well, result was the same wonky thing, only difference was the rotation alignment (which I could care less about in that regard).
Heck, they won't stay on their place along the BBone where they should. Is this bugged or am I just stupid? Please help.

Comment: A Bendy Bone is like a Bezier curve. It has 2 handles and the curvature is calculated by the handles. I'm not sure if you can align 4 normal bones along the B-Bone. Mainly because you don't know the curvature. An Armature bone constraint gives also weird results.

Comment: Hm, after quick research I would say that the *Armature Bone Contraint* is the key and should work. Maybe I did something wrong. Have a look here: https://youtu.be/hUdefdwx-CM